# IE 8 plays sound, Ulead pop-up message appears, crash

Tags: internet-explorer-8, outlook-web-access, aol

I'm experiencing a problem on a new PC using Outlook Web Access in Internet Explorer 8. When OWA plays a sound, a message box appears: the about box for Ulead MP3 codec. When I click OK to dismiss the box, I get a message that IE has stopped responding and Windows eventually has to force the browser window closed.

This is apparently [not an isolated incident](http://www.google.com/search?q=ulead+mp3+codec), occurring on computers from different manufacturers and on other websites that play sound (such as AOL's Webmail).

The only "fix" I've found on [discussion boards](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/7b7ef8dd-c714-4bec-abff-4860800ae07f) is to prevent the website from playing sound in the first place. That's not a fix, that's just avoiding the trigger. I'd like to know what's causing this and uninstall it or repair it, so the computer can work like it's supposed to.

Since Super User users are smarter than the average bear, I thought I'd have better luck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by uninstalling two bundled applications from Corel. The message box no longer appears and the crash no longer happens. This is still not really a "fix" (fortunately I have no use for the apps).